# Why use foreign accents in English language movies when unnecessary?

Tags: dialogue, film-techniques

I've recently watched the movie **[Child 44](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_44_(film))**, which is set in the 1950's Soviet Union during the Stalin regime. Apart from the fact that the movie itself is not memorable in my opinion, the thing that has bugged me the most is the way characters talk, which is in English language but with a strong eastern (Russian) accent. And I've been asking myself troughout the whole movie, why is that "necessary"?

[**Child 44 - Movie Trailer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uia6y9SRsj4)

What could possibly be the reason behind the choice of making Russian characters speak in that manner? They are all Russians, they are not interacting with foreigners, so why the thick accent?

Of course I understand the obvious choice of making a movie in English language, for commercial and casting reasons, but I still don't understand the need of constantly reminding us that they are Russians by using this annoying ruse and throwing some "Da" around.

I understand the reason for characterization (for instance: Italian-American mobsters), but this seems completely unjustified to me.

Does anybody know the reason (if there's any) behind this choice?

I'm positive that this is not the first, nor the only movie in which this "technique" for dialogues has been adopted, but I can't remember other examples at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like this trope: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JustAStupidAccent

Comment: I think this is just to make the audience aware that these are foreigners, e.g. non americans.

Comment: @Josh - I was hoping for a better (if not deeper) reason than that ... But I guess the "stupid-accent" trope will have to do ... :) Thanks for that

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer. More for a related list of examples.

Comment: What accent would you prefer? [Queen's English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYuTOjg6LvI)? Flippancy aside, everyone has some kind of accent, so why not pick one that's close to where your characters are supposed to originate...

Comment: @Basic *everyone has some kind of accent* That's true but I can't shake the feeling of weirdness watching Russian characters struggling to speak a foreign language in their own country. But maybe I'm the weird one :)  - Nice tutorial by the way :P

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, and English is not my primary language so I'm not specially good with accents, but are there people that shouldn't speak Russian in that movie? For example, German, or something else? That could be a way to differentiate their origin. Plus each languages has their intonation, and that could help to show emotions ("natural" intonations in some words, or expression").

Comment: @Larme - English is not my native language too, I'm Italian. I guess I would be able to distinguish between english, australian or american, but I'm not so sure. *are there people that shouldn't speak Russian in that movie?* Not as far as I remember. There are only Russians speaking to other Russians ...

Comment: without there being an actual answer yet - I think @Thomas hits the nail on the head... it's no good if they're just 'foreign'.. the audience has to *absolutely know* they're 'foreign'... all the time [in case they forget]. I imagine this works equally for any mono-linguistic movie, from whatever country. Let the audience follow the plot, without having to keep 'extraneous detail' too. Though in defence of the OP, see [The Meaning of Liff - Aberbeeg](http://tmoliff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/aberbeeg-vb.html)